# home is not working in wordpreess

Tags: theme-development, themes

all Inner pages are working fine but home page is not  working admin is working fine

home page not working I have added wp-confing file

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

but not get any error

home page dispaly blank
I have  check all plugin disable but still error are coming

Comment: describe more..

Comment: Patel Jignesh   my site home page is blank all inner page are  working i have change setting  in admin for home page still not working

Comment: you try or not save permalink if no then just try it. hope work? and any error in console?

Comment: I have check to  permalink not working home page  Patel Jignesh

Comment: This sounds more like a theme problem. What theme are you using?

Comment: Nathan Powell twentyseventeen

Comment: i have slow this question i need to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to remove "/" in a wp-option table  site URL

Answer (score 0):

Please try disabling all your Plugins by going to your File Manager through cpanel, **in wp-content folder rename the plugins folder to "Plugins-old"** and then check if the homepage is back. If it is not then **try disabling the themes by renaming the folder** the same way as well. If the homepage still isn't back then, can you provide the URL of the site so I can have a look?

Let me know if this works or not. :)

Comment: Afnan abbasi  please check my comment  
 I have all try it